# Can I access my account from a different computer?

Tags: users

My university has Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to download Ubuntu on my laptop. Will I be able to connect to the same user? And if yes do I have to have the 14.04 version or it doesn't matter?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Set up an identical system locally, and copy the users files, or connect to a remote system?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your account via ssh:

```
ssh username@serverip
```

where username is the name of your account and serverip is the IP of the university machine.

Comment: Ok thanks and i am guessing the ubuntu version doesnt matter?

Comment: That's right, it doesn't matter. You can use some software in Windows too, like putty, to conect to your account.

Comment: @VagosKatsiko, ... but the system at the university must be an ssh server (ssh-server software must be installed to make it possible to connect via ssh).